# Vuejs SPA dynamic theme

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, webpack

I have a Vuejs single page application that I have built, and I would like to add user-switchable dynamic themes. Something where the user has a button somewhere or something and they can click a 'light' or 'dark' theme option and the whole app updates right away. I would also like to have all of my 'theme' scss files be local.

This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46730904/user-switchable-custom-themes-with-vue-js) is the closest I've found so far, but the themes are not local.

```js
const themes = {
  flatly: "https://bootswatch.com/4/flatly/bootstrap.min.css",
  materia: "https://bootswatch.com/4/materia/bootstrap.min.css",
  solar: "https://bootswatch.com/4/solar/bootstrap.min.css"
};
```

If I could figure out how to get this answer to work with local theme files that would be great, but switching the link paths out with a local path doesn't work.

```js
const themes = {
  dark: "dark-theme.scss",
  light: "light-theme.scss"
};
```

My suspicion is that this doesn't work because of Webpack or some other compiling problem where the scss files are not included.

I have found I can get my theme files to appear in the client source if I add something like the following to my index.html
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= BASE_URL %>dark-theme.scss">`
But then I don't know how to reference this in my app. Maybe a link like `http://localhost:8080/dark-theme.scss`? But then I don't think that would work in production (and it doesn't work locally anyway).

I have also looked at:

- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844545/replacin) which is a similar idea to the answer linked above and runs into similar problems
- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49551205/best-way-to-dynamically-change-theme-of-my-vue-js-spa) which only has scss variables and wouldn't be able to add attributes to a class for example
- [this](https://medium.com/maestral-solutions/coloring-your-app-implementing-live-theming-with-vue-js-and-styled-components-29e428900394) which I don't find to be a very clean solution as it requires all components to know about themes and such

I've also tried doing something like `import "@/path/to/theme.scss";` in my `main.ts` file which *does* work, but I don't know how I'd leverage that to make the themes switchable. It just adds an element like the following to my head, which has no id or class so I can't effectively query it to switch it out. Using `require` does something similar as well.

```html
<style type="text/css" >
  ...
</style>
```

Comment: I had a similar problem with a customer some weeks ago. IMHO, the best way to achieve this is to import the two themes as you mentioned in `main.ts`, then using a JavaScript method to supply what media queries doesn’t: I mean, on browsers that don’t support them yet. It’s 3 AM here, but I’ll follow your question and possible answers from tomorrow!

Comment: @FedericoMoretti Thank you, I'd love to see an answer for this. Let me know if there is any ambiguity in my post that I can clear up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

main.ts:

```
import "@/path/to/dark-theme.scss"
import "@/path/to/light-theme.scss"
```

dark-theme.scss:

```
body.dark {
  /* rest of the theme */
}
```

light-theme.scss:

```
body.ligh {
  /* rest of the theme */
}
```

index.html (or injecting it from main.ts depending on local-storage or OS's mode):

```
<body class="light">
```

Where you have your switch:

```
methods: {
  toggleTheme() {
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark')
    document.body.classList.toggle('light')
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work well. I'd still prefer if I didn't need the `body.dark` and could just have a scss file with all the css at the root level, but this seems perfectly acceptable. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a trick that came to my mind you can use. Create two empty components for your theme like this:

```
<template><div></div></template>
<script>export default {name: 'DarkTheme'}</script>
<style>
  @import "~@/path/to/theme.scss"
</style>
```

now in your app you can use v-if on these two components like

```
<dark-theme v-if="theme == 'dark'"/>
<light-theme v-if="theme == 'light'"/>
```

PS: 
this code is not tested